# Nhibernate id generator or MySQL auto-increment

Tags: mysql, nhibernate

I am just starting my adventure with writing an app that has to work with database. I've started by designing my database in MySQL Workbench, exported this project to the server and now I want to try writing some code, that will be able to talk with this server.

I've decided to try using NHibernate, but I'am stuck at writing mappings for the Id/Primary key property/column. I've read, that I must specify the generator, but does that mean, that I have to remove auto-increment from this column in a database?

If answer to previous question is negative, then which NH generator will work correctly with server driven auto-increment generator. If it's positive, then which generator is preferable? Or maybe, even if NH can work with server's AI, you still recommend to remove AI from columns and use client based generator (so again, which?).

Comment: Have you checked this: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator?

Comment: Yes, I did, but I am not sure, if I understand correctly. Is `identity` generator the right answer?

Comment: preferred mapping would be `native` *(based on sql dialect, NHibernates will properly expect that ID is generated at DB)*. But `identity` for IDENTITY id columns is ok. **NOTE:** I for years live with identity.. but if I could choose, sequence or HILO would be my choice. It does not require real INSERT to let DB generate the key...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since there was no direct answer to this question (there was comment that gave me the answer instead) and I want to close it, I'll write one.

My problem here was the understanding of the functionality name - GENERATOR. When you have a server based generator (auto increment), why do you need another in your app? That was the source of my mistake. Actually, this in app generator does not have to really generate anything, it can fetch data from database, but still, for this app, it will have no difference.

So, TL;DR
As @RadimKöhler wrote in his comment to my question, both `native` and `identity` work well with autoincrement/identity (or whatever name is used by your database engine) column in database.

now, time for quote:

> NOTE: I for years live with identity.. but if I could choose, sequence or HILO would be my choice. It does not require real INSERT to let DB generate the key...

... think about it :) I haven't gone this way, because I am writing a small app which will be used by single user most of the time. Usage of an actual in-app generator let's you work with data kept in memory, which can be flushed in one go to the database.